# Which Permissions are not allowed for a java "Rich Internet Application" since java 7u45?

Tags: java, security, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm aware that since java 7u45 and 7u51 the restrictions for launching a java application via applet/webstart have been tightened.

However, previously if you specified  in a jnlp, for example, you would actually get all permissions (imagine that) -- but now, if you specify "Permissions: all-permissions" in the manifest of the main jar, you do not get all permissions.

Some that I know you do not get are:

```
java.net.NetPermission "specifyStreamHandler"
java.util.PropertyPermission "*" "read,write"
java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers"
```

I keep running into these and I'd like to have a master list of what you can and cannot do so it's not just by trial and error. Does anyone know of such a list?

Comment: I think permission wise on the java site  nothing has changed. There are some changes to the deployment and signatur checking as well as to livescript in some later updates. Those changes are documented in the release notes and deployment guides.

Comment: Related: [New security requirements for RIAs in 7u51 (January 2014)](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias). And also see: [Java’s Losing Security Legacy](http://threatpost.com/javas-losing-security-legacy). Mimoso recommends *not* signing so you can't break out of the sandbox.

Comment: @jww thank you. I've read those, and adhered to all the new security requirements, but I still don't get ALL permissions, just most. For example, no matter what you do you can't read/write any system properties that don't start "jnlp." My application needs full read/write permission to the user's hard drive, so I have to sign and use all permissions.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to add this to your jnlp file:

```
<security>
   <all-permissions/>
</security>
```

and add this to manifest:

```
Permissions: all-permissions
```

If permission is not needed you still need this except you have to put 'sandbox' instead of 'all-permission'.

Comment: This is incorrect. I have spent days on this -- recursively unzipping all my jars, unsigining, re-signing while adding the "Permissions" attribute, the "Codebase" attribute, and any/all other security-related attributes to the manifest. I've signed the JNLP, I've added <all-permissions> to the JNLP. It does NOT give you all permissions. You're still in a semi-sandbox. That's what the question is about.

Comment: Can you give an example of a java operation that throws security exception when you run your Java webstart application?

Comment: sure: `java.lang.System.getProperty("my.property")`. If you do that in a jar that's not the "main" jar in the jnlp, it raises an access control exception for `java.util.PropertyPermission`

Comment: You're right, there are some new restrictions and this could be one of them. Reading your original question I noticed you're looking for a list of limitations rather than workaround solutions. Have you considered just writting a webstart java code with many SecurityManager.checkPermission() calls for each permission? To get list of various permissions you can refer to this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/permissions.html

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty good idea. I may try that. I wonder if there's a way to introspect and get that list of permissions programatically... I may play with that. THanks

Comment: I wonder too. They have a class called AllPermission so if you call SecurityManager.checkPermission(new AllPermission()) it may automatically check it for everything and throw exception upon reaching the first permission that is not allowed. I haven't tried it but curious to know so let us know the result if you try it.